# SQLCMD fails on INSERT with "Syntax error at line xxxxx near command '&'"

Tags: sql-server, sqlcmd

I use SQLCMD to import DDL generated by mssql-scripter and i got this error:

[image]

The offending INSERT is the following:

> INSERT [dbo].[Settings_ContentPartFieldDefinitionRecord] ([Id], [Name], [Settings], [ContentFieldDefinitionRecord_id], [ContentPartDefinitionRecord_Id]) VALUES (12, N'JavascripttoRun', N'<settings DisplayName="Javascript to Run" InsertStuffFieldSettings.RawHtml="<script type="text/javascript">
>  $(document).ready(function() {
>   ShowAdvancedLinkSettings();
>  });
>  $("#AdvancedLink_LinkType_Value").change(function() {
>   ShowAdvancedLinkSettings();
>  });
>  
>  function ShowAdvancedLinkSettings() {
>   switch($("#AdvancedLink_LinkType_Value").val()) {
>    case "External":
>     $(".content-picker-field[data-field-name=''InternalContent'']").hide()
>     $("#AdvancedLink_Caption_Text").parent().hide();
>     $("#AdvancedLink_ExternalUrl_Value").parent().parent().show();
>     $("#AdvancedLink_UrlBancaDati_Value").parent().parent().hide();
>     break;
>    case "Internal":
>     $("#AdvancedLink_ExternalUrl_Value").parent().parent().hide();
>     $(".content-picker-field[data-field-name=''InternalContent'']").show()
>     $("#AdvancedLink_Caption_Text").parent().show();
>     $("#AdvancedLink_UrlBancaDati_Value").parent().parent().hide();
>     break;
>  case "Banca dati":
>     $("#AdvancedLink_ExternalUrl_Value").parent().parent().hide();
>     $(".content-picker-field[data-field-name=''InternalContent'']").hide()
>     $("#AdvancedLink_Caption_Text").parent().hide();
>     $("#AdvancedLink_UrlBancaDati_Value").parent().parent().show();
>     break;
>    default:
>     $("#AdvancedLink_ExternalUrl_Value").parent().parent().hide();
>     $(".content-picker-field[data-field-name=''InternalContent'']").hide()
>     $("#AdvancedLink_Caption_Text").parent().hide();
>     $("#AdvancedLink_UrlBancaDati_Value").parent().parent().hide();
>     break;
>   }
>  }
> </script>
>
> " InsertStuffFieldSettings.OnFooter="true" />', 7, 51)

The INSERT is correct, if i run it with SSMS or Azure Data Studio it works.

I found on internet various articles with similar error messages but no solutions that worked for me.

Any ideas?

Comment: [Please do not upload images of code/data/errors when asking a question.](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551)

Comment: That error and the `INSERT` statement don't appear to be related; there is no `&` in that query.

Comment: You ran SQLCMD from CMD. & is mostly equivalent to ; (end of command) in most programming languages. Try running from PowerShell. Or better yet, use either Invoke-SqlCmd in SQLPS or Invoke-DbaQuery from DBATOOLS.

Answer (score 1):

It come out that SQLCMD has a mechanism of variables with the format  $(variable_name) that can be replaced at run time .

My data are not meant to be such variables, with the effect of fooling the mechanism and cause the error.

The solution is to use the -x option which suppresses the variable substitution mechanism (for reference see https://learn.microsoft.com/it-it/sql/tools/sqlcmd/sqlcmd-utility?view=sql-server-ver16).